# How to get a list of files loaded by browser with last request using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, http

I'm a newby in javascript world and I have a question: is there any way to get an access to a list of files that has been loaded by browser with last request? 
What do I mean: when browser loads a web page it also loads not only html file but also css, jpeg and etc. I would like to know by javascript script on the page what were the filenames of those loaded files.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use the browser's built-in developer tools to see that?

Comment: I need it in the javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this is a neat solution, but with jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$('script').each(function(){
var file = $(this).attr("src");
$( "#result" ).append( file + "<br />" ); 
});

$('link').each(function(){
var file = $(this).attr("href");
 $( "#result" ).append( file + "<br />"); 
});

$('img').each(function(){
var file = $(this).attr("src");
 $( "#result" ).append( file + "<br />"); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mdp9J/3/

And in pure Javascript maybe like this:

```
var script = document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT");
for (var i = 0; i < script.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += script[i].src + "<br />";
}

var image = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += image[i].src + "<br />";
}

var link = document.getElementsByTagName("LINK");
for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += link[i].href + "<br />";
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lotc8dda/